# is this wcf service efficient?

Tags: performance, wcf

Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface Idemo
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "check?Value1={id}&Value2={name}&Value3={city}",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string GetData(string id,string name);
}
```

class

```
public class demo : Idemo
{
public string GetData(string id,string name,string city) 
    {           

       DataTable tb;
        tb = con.GetDataTable("query");
        tb.TableName = "data";                     
        System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        tb.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema, false);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

return table looks like below

```
sem sub1 sub2 sub3

 1   50   40   30

 2   60   20   40
```

is the interface design good? I'm not using any contract. is any other way to speed up?

i heard that convert DataSet into a custom DataContract and send it.. is it possible in my scenario?

Comment: Why do you want to speed it up? Have you determined it's too slow?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a performance problem it is not in the code that you have posted.

The name of the method that you use to get data is "getDataTable" you also mention the use of DataSets.

The use of datasets has an overhead, you should look at optimising how you get data out of the database.